# Is there any way to add tawk.to chat service to my flutter application

Tags: flutter, tawk.to

I have searched many places. But still I can't find a solution. I want implement a live chat assistance for my app. I have seen tawk.to service have been using by some app builders. But I don't know how they implemented it.

Any alternatives for tawk.to can be also considered.

Answer (score 2):

you can open the chat link directly via a webview plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_view).
I used this solution with a customized domain name on the tawk whitelabel addon.
[WHITE LABEL ADDON, CUSTOM CHAT DOMAIN NAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djO7O.png)